# storing Rest Controller Response post controller has returned response to request

Tags: spring-boot

I have a rest controller. I want to write a response to file for tracking purpose,however I dont want controller to wait till writing is finished.  How can we make controller to return respond immediately and post that write response to file.  I tried making write method as @Async but controller is not returning response till writing is finished.  Any idea how can we achieve this?

Comment: `@Async` is the way forward. Can you show us what you wrote that's blocking?

Answer (score 0):

[Logback](https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/) is the default logger in spinrg boot. Use an asynchronous [appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html). Something like below. You can just log the response before you send it back, logback will deal with the rest.

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>myapp.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```